# Java webservice returning error when consumed by c# client

Tags: java, c#, web-services

I have a service reference in my solution, this reference is setted to a Java webservice, but I don't have access to its code.

Everytime I call this web service, I'm getting the following error:

> Java class com.thomson.ecom.service.bean.product.Material doesn't
>   support necessary mechanism for marshalling/unmarshalling.  Adapter
>   error.  element text content may not contain START_ELEMENT; nested
>   exception is com.thomson.mis.xml.TypeSupportException: Java class
>   com.thomson.ecom.service.bean.product.Material doesn't support
>   necessary mechanism for marshalling/unmarshalling.  Adapter error. 
>   element text content may not contain START_ELEMENT

My code:

```
using(var ws = new WebServiceX.ServiceCliente())
{

    var obj = new ProductInformation
    {
         ProductId = "TEST"
    };

    ws.EndPoint.Address = new EndpointAddres("http://myurl.com");

    var ret = ws.MyMethod(obj);

}
```

I already tried with a web reference, but I get the same error. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue I had was with service version. After I've started to inform the service version in the header object, it started to work.